Average number of calls coming into office X, in one hour, is $4$, to Y is $7$. What is the prob. that on some day $100$ calls will come to both?
A certain company has two offices, $X$ and $Y$, operating independently, $8$ hours a day.
The average number of calls coming into office X, in one hour, is $4$.
The average number of calls coming into office Y, the number is $7$.
Determine the probability that on some fixed day a total of exactly $100$ calls will come into both offices.

So, the average number of calls per day for:

Office $X$: $\lambda_X = 4/ \text{hour} \implies 32/ \text{day}$
Office $Y$: $\lambda_Y = 7/ \text{hour} \implies 56/ \text{day}$

Numbers of calls received in one day at offices $X$ and $Y$ follow Poisson distribution with parameters $\lambda_X = 32$ , $\lambda_Y = 56$.
The total number of calls received in one day at both offices, $Z=X+Y$, follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda_X + \lambda_Y= 32+56 = 88$.
Therefore, $Z$ is Poisson distributed with $\lambda = 88$
Substitute $λ=88$ and $k=100$:
$$P(Z = 100) = \frac{88^{100} \cdot e^{-88}}{100!}$$
Is that correct?

This is correct, though you should include the assumption that the two random variables, $X$, and $Y$, are independent in order to conclude the distribution of $Z=X+Y$.
